# Easy mock does not recognize mocked service

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I encounter this strange issues while testing one of my services...
I am mocking two services with easymock 3.0 and injecting them with Spring, but i get a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock: $Proxy43" exception at one of them. I am declaring them the same way in my configuration file, like this:

```
<bean id="recurringSchedulesJobsService" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.spmsoftware.recurringschedules.service.RecurringSchedulesJobsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobPeriodService" class="org.easymock.EasyMock" factory-method="createMock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.spmsoftware.jobdefinition.service.JobPeriodService"/>
</bean>
```

In my junit tests, i'm using them the folowing way:

```
@Autowired
private RecurringSchedulesJobsService recurringSchedulesJobsService;
@Autowired
private JobPeriodService jobPeriodService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    reset(recurringSchedulesJobsService);
    expect(recurringSchedulesJobsService.getBasedOnRecurringScheduleId(RECURRING_SCHEDULE_ID)).andReturn(buildRecurringScheduleJob());
    replay(recurringSchedulesJobsService);

    reset(jobPeriodService);
    expect(jobPeriodService.findPeriodByJobId(RECURRING_SCHEDULE_JOB_ID)).andReturn(buildJobDefinitionPeriod());
    replay(jobPeriodService);
}
```

recurringSchedulesJobsService gets mocked and when i comment the second service, it behaves as expected. jobPeriodService, on the other hand, is not recognized as a mock. Instead i get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a mock: $Proxy43
at org.easymock.internal.ClassExtensionHelper.getControl(ClassExtensionHelper.java:66)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.getControl(EasyMock.java:2068)
at org.easymock.EasyMock.reset(EasyMock.java:1983)
at com.spmsoftware.recurringschedules.occurrences.generator.OccurrenceGeneratorTest.setUp(OccurrenceGeneratorTest.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
```

The exception is thrown only be the reset() method, though...

One interesting thing i found is that the two objects are not of the same instance. This is what i get when debugging:

[image]

Any ideas on this would be very valuable.
Thanks

Comment: Are both of recurringSchedulesJobsService and jobPeriodService interfaces?

Answer (score 5):

Spring wraps the bean into a proxy, probably in order to apply AOP aspects (transactional, security) around the methods. So the bean it injects inside your test is a Spring proxy around the mock, and not the mock itself.

Why are you using a spring context and dependency injection, though? You could simply instantiate your service object in your unit test, inject mock dependencies in the object, and test it. No need for a Spring container for that. That's probably the main interesting feature of an IoC framework: it makes unit tests simple:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.recurringSchedulesJobsService = mock(RecurringSchedulesJobsService.class);
    this.jobPeriodService = mock(JobPeriodService.class);
}

@Test
public void testSomeMethod() {
    expect(recurringSchedulesJobsService.doThis()).andReturn(that);
    expect(jobPeriodService.doThat()).andReturn(1);

    replay(recurringSchedulesJobsService, jobPeriodService);

    MyServiceImplementation serviceToTest = 
        new MyServiceImplementation(recurringSchedulesJobsService, jobPeriodService);
    serviceToTest.someMethod();
    verify(recurringSchedulesJobsService, jobPeriodService);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for thw quick answer. 
I'm using spring so that I don't have to inject all of jobPeriodService's dependencies. I've tried the programmatic approach, but i have to handle all the other services i normally autowire in jobPeriodService. Anyway, why does Spring only behave like this for my second mock? Why does the first work?

Comment: jobPeriodService is a mock. There is nothing to inject in a mock!?

Comment: I get NPE when i try to use it because of a null entityManager

Comment: That probably means that the service is a class (not an interface), and that you didn't mock the method called by your service under test. A unit test should only test one unit. All its dependencies should be mocked.

Comment: Yeah, it is a class. The reference is an interface. The test does cover quite a lot of logic. That is why i am trying to mock as much as possible.

Comment: So, mock all the methods that are used by your test. That's what you should do. The test shouldn't rely on any concrete implementation of any JobPeriodService method.

Comment: I am trying to mock the methods, but i can not, because of the exception i mentioned in my post.

Comment: We're turning in circle. 1. Don't use a Spring context for your unit tests: do everything programmatically, as shown in my answer. 2. Make sure that every method of JobPeriodeService that is called by the method under test is mocked.

Comment: We are turning in circles... I've managed to make my tests work, by subclassing the JobPeriodeService in a hand made mock that I inject with Spring. I think it's better than dropping Spring's injection for the entire tests. But my question still remains open... Why does it treat those two services differentrly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jobPeriodService is being auto-proxied by Spring whereas recurringSchedulesJobsService is not. That's most likely because Spring has marked recurringSchedulesJobService not eligible for auto-proxying (no potential pointcut match, it's explicitly turned off somewhere, etc.) I don't really know what the specific reason is without looking at your other configuration

If you turn up the logging level of Spring to DEBUG, it should tell you why recurringSchedulesJobService isn't eligible for auto-proxying.

Comment: I'm with JB Nizet, though. You're making this too complicated.